# Objective-C equivalent of a flash action script function

Tags: objective-c

Learning basic Objective-C and have a few beginner questions.
How would I define and implement a method which takes two (or three) arguments within my class?
I find the syntax to pass multiple arguments into a method really confusing. I would really appreciate any help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a simple 2-argument method implementation:

```
-(int)myMethodThatMultipiesThisNumber:(int)x byThisOne:(int)y
{
    return x * y;
}
```

You would invoke it like:

```
int z = [myObject myMethodThatMultipliesThisNumber:6 byThisOne:9];
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Edit: Based on your comment below, it seems like you're missing a fundamental feature of Objective-C messaging - that the method name is *interleaved* with the arguments.  Check out [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6) from [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2) for all the detail you need.

Comment: yes, but I don't understand in your example what is byThisOne?

Comment: You can also use normal C style stuff: `int myInt(x, y)`.

Comment: @GrAnD, tt's part of the method name, which is "`myMethodThatMultipliesThisNumber:byThisOne:`".  It's completely optional, but recommended to have.  It's just how Objective-C is.

Comment: @GrAnD 'byThisOne' doesn't do anything but make the code more readable for a human.

Comment: Yes, I guess I can use normal C style (which seems to be easier to understand) but I wanna "get" objective-c syntax

Comment: @GrAnD - you *cannot* use C style functions if you want to make class/instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's "The Objective-C Programming Language" document provides a nice overview of [Object Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW5) including an explanation of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you are interested in iPhone programming, I would watch the first three classes of [Paul Hegarty's CS193P class from Stanford](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/).

Those first three classes have very little iPhone specific stuff, instead, classes 1 and three go over the features and syntax of Objective C, and class 2 goes over basic use of Xcode (which, if you want to do Objective C work, is likely the IDE you will be using). Other than the fact that it goes VERY fast (which may actually be what you are looking for) you would be hard pressed to find a better "quick overview" of Objective C.